# Best way to dynamic creation of file input

Tags: javascript, html

I have some custom upload file options like multiple hyperlinks. When clicked on that, I need to trigger the hidden file input. Say, I have 10 hyperlinks to upload different icons.
There are two ways to do that:
1. Create 10 file inputs and hide them and manually trigger them when clicking on the respective hyperlink.
2. Create a common function for that when the user clicks on the hyperlink and in that function, create a file input using javascript and triggered it using js.

So, my question is that which one is best or there is an efficient way to do that.

Answer (score 4):

You can try by creating single `input type='file'` and limit the by [accepted file types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#Limiting_accepted_file_types)  like this using `accept` attribute

```
<input type="file" id="profile_pic" name="profile_pic"
          accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png">
```

Comment: Thanks, but each input files have different name. So according to your answer how can I identify which icon is being uploaded ?

Comment: My question is that, should I create 10 file inputs to DOM and hide them or create dynamically when user click on respective hyperlinks

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can use the createElement function to create the input fields `.createElement()` then append those elements with `.appendChild()` to wherever you need.

So you can probably make a function to create the appropriate input field:

```
function appendInput(inputType){
    if(inputType==1){
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
      $('body').appendChild(input);//just replace body with whatever element you want to append the input to e.g $('#someDivId').appendChild(input);
    }else if(inputType==2){
      //some other input
    }/...
  }
```

But if you simply trying to input different types of files, brk's answer is much more efficient

Hope that helps

**EDIT** Also having 10 different input fields that you hide and display would be somewhat bad from a maintenance perspective, so I would advocate creating different input fields depending on the hyperlink clicked.

**EDIT2** from what I read you need each input to have a different name so you simply change the function to :

```
function(inputName){
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    input.setAttribute('name', inputName);//pass the name of each input field
    $('body').appendChild(input);
}
```

Comment: You just over complicated things.